# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ultralytics.yolo' when trying to use export.py from ultralytics

Tags: pytorch, yolo, modulenotfounderror, darknet

I´m trying to use the export.py script from the ultralytics repository in github (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5). Previously I installed all the requirements by using the command:

```
    pip install -U -r requirements.txt
```

But when I use:

```
    python export.py --img-size 640 --batch-size 1 --weights ../best.pt
```

I get the following error:

[No module named 'ultralytics.yolo' (IMAGE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzLbU.png)

Any idea on how to solve this error?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I was just using the repository incorrectly. As I wanted to export the neural network from pyTorch format to ONNX, I just needed to execute the following command:

```
    yolo export model=<my_model> format=onnx imgsz=224,128
```

Now it works correctly.